# How to find all files with size greater than say 100MB in hdfs through command line?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, command-line-interface

How can I find all files with size greater than 100MB in hdfs through command line?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
hadoop fs find / -type f -size 100 -print \
```

Comment: This doesn't work, there's a syntax issue here (should be `hadoop fs -find`) and `-size` and `-type` are not available as arguments.